# returning a Tuple with a null item

Tags: c#

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public Tuple<bool, SomeObjectModel> CheckIfJsonIsValid(string IncomingJson)
{
   SomeObjectModel TheObjectModel = new SomeObjectModel();
   JavascriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
   .....

   try
   {
       TheObjectModel = TheSerializer.Deserialize<SomeObjectModel>(IncomingJson);
   }
   catch
   {
       return new Tuple<bool, SomeObjectModel>(false, null); //question here
   }

   .....
   return new Tuple<bool, SomeObjectModel>(true, TheObjectModel);
}
```

The calling method first check the returning tuple's Item1, and if it's false, ends its process.

Is it better practice a) to return a null value in the Tuple or b) to return a new and fresh instance of SomeObjectModel? Are there any performance implications?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Unless the constructor does *lots* of work, there are "no practical performance implications". Let the performance tests do the talking; now, which approach represents your model better? And, is a Tuple needed at all if "returning a null model object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest three alternative solutions:

---

**ParseJsonIfValid**: If deserializing works, TheObjectModel is always non-null. Thus, there is no need for the boolean:

```
public SomeObjectModel ParseJsonIfValid(string IncomingJson)
{
   JavascriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
   .....

   try
   {
       return TheSerializer.Deserialize<SomeObjectModel>(IncomingJson);
   }
   catch
   {
       return null;
   }
}
```

In the calling function simply check whether the return value is null or not.

---

**ParseJson**: If the JSON is *usually* valid, and invalid JSON is a sign of something gone terribly wrong, just throw an exception:

```
public SomeObjectModel ParseJson(string IncomingJson)
{
   JavascriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
   .....

   try
   {
       return TheSerializer.Deserialize<SomeObjectModel>(IncomingJson);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       throw new TheServerSentRubbishException(e);
   }
}
```

Be sure to include the inner ("real") exception, so that the calling function can log the real cause of the error for debugging purposes.

---

**TryParseJson**: If `null` can be a *valid* deserialization, you can use the following pattern, which has the advantage of being consistent with the `TryParse` methods of the .NET framework:

```
public bool TryParseJson(string IncomingJson, out SomeObjectModel theObjectModel)
{
   JavascriptSerializer TheSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
   .....

   try
   {
       theObjectModel = TheSerializer.Deserialize<SomeObjectModel>(IncomingJson);
       return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```